# Base Textures applying to parts of model, the rest is transparent

Tags: texturing, shaders

bit of a blender noob here. I'm trying to rip a game model, and the base textures aren't applying correctly to the model via shader editor. Some of the textures are applying to the correct locations, but the rest is completely transparent. The SSS and ILM textures work fine, and apply entirely and correctly. I was recommended to change the alpha settings of the base colour texture to none, but that didn't work at all. I was following a guide, and they completely glossed over this as a possible issue. Its my first time using it, so I'm pretty confused, and I kind of don't know what I'm doing without help.

Attached is what the base textures look like right now, and what the SSS textures look like (and what the base textures SHOULD look like, minus different colours).
[image: Blender full screenshot with model, selected, displaying only a portion of the textures displayed in the image editor. The rest of the model is completely transparent.]

as requested by moonboots: [image]
I noticed that this file in particular seems to be missing the default nodes in shader editor. I don't know how i manage to do these things without trying.

[image: Example of the SSS texture applying correctly, leaving no transparency on the model.]

Comment: update: i attempted to restart the rip and i am getting the same results. i doubt its an issue with this particular file.

Comment: Hello could you please share your file, read the instructions here: https://blend-exchange.com/ or use another platform

Comment: @moonboots added

Comment: Thanks but you didn't pack your images, you need to go into File > External Data >Pack Resources, save and share again, if the file is too heavy use another platform (workupload for example)

Comment: @moonboots thank you for letting me know. trying again...!

Comment: @moonboots updated. my apologies, i havent used that before.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it has to do with the format of your image, you need to *Save as* a copy of your image as PNG for example:

[image]

Then reimport in your material, plug the *Image Texture* and it will work:

[image]

By the way the texture was not visible in *Solid* mode only, and in *Solid* mode the *Viewport Shading* was set to *Color > Texture*, if you switch to *Material* you'll see the classic *Solid* grey shader:

[image]

Comment: yes, this worked. thank you! i wont have nightmares tonight!